# Select rows from a column within the first 45 minutes of the past 1 hour

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select rows from a column that were submitted within the first 45 minutes of the last 1 hour plus the last 15 minutes of the hour before that. Basically, it is to query form submissions through a cron job that gives people who might be submitting the form (which has multiple parts) as the cron job is running to have 15 minutes or so to be able to fill out the form before sending their information while it is incomplete.

Currently, this works for selecting rows within the last hour:

`SELECT row FROM column WHERE (time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`

Does anyone know how I could change this query to have a 15 minute cut off so it selects rows that have been submitted within an hour prior to the last 15 minutes the cron job runs?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please add your complete query.

Comment: It was a simple SELECT query. I have added the entire query now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND
time <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

`15` can be changed to `20` if you like to have the first 40 minutes (question body text) instead of 45 minutes (question title).

-edit-

In your new situation, I understand you want to have a moving window of 1 hour for the cron job, so you could do that like this:

```
time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 75 MINUTE) AND
time <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

However, this is dangerous because your job will have to run in exactly the right time otherwise you will have misses anyway. It's better to flag the items you have processed. In the query you can exclude the items that have been processed before. This way, you won't risk processing an item twice. If the cron has stopped for some reason, you can just run it again to process all unprocessed items.

Comment: I realized after posting that I needed to not just include 45 minutes but 60 minutes with a cut off of the last 15 minutes. I have edited the question. I apologize, but thank you for your initial answer. This worked for me until I realized it would simply never send out any forms submitted in the x time I'm deducting from the query every hour.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's almost the same query, but you could change the first condition to `INTERVAL 75 minutes`. However, this is dangerous because your job will have to run in exactly the right time otherwise you will have misses anyway. It's better to flag the items you have processed. In the query you can exclude the items that have been processed before.